# How do I call a function when an element changes?

Tags: jquery

This is a rails app. I have the following function, which is called when the page loads.

```
<script>
mainclearfix = function () {
   #do something
}
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', mainclearfix);
</script>
```

Later on, I will use the following script to render a partial and replace html through a js.erb file:

```
<script>
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  if($('#latest-scrolling').size() > 0) {
   #do something
   $.getScript(change)
  }
});
</script>
```

The `NewsController` turns to `news.js.erb` to `respond_to` `$.getScript(change)`

```
 news.js.erb
 $('.news-section').html('<%= escape_javascript render :partial  => "news/latest"  %>');
```

Now that `$('.news-section')` has changed, I need to run the `mainclearfix` function again.

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
$('.news-section').on('change', mainclearfix);
```

Comment: the change event only works on input / select elements https://api.jquery.com/change/ , so that explains why your last line doesn't work. Why can't you just call clearfix from news.js.erb ?

Comment: yeah that works. submit as an answer and i will accept it. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `clearfix();` directly from the `news.js.erb` file.